# Reset input & output textarea in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, reset

in simple html/js (withouth jquery), I have to reset all textareas contained in a form. Here are my attempts:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#">

  Source:<br><br>

  <textarea id="tab_source" name="source" rows=6>
original default text
</textarea><br><br> Result:

  <br><br>

  <textarea id="tab_result" name="result" rows=6>
</textarea><br><br>

  <input name="button" type="button" value="GO!" onclick="transform()">
  <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset test 1">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(" myForm ").reset();" value="Reset test 2">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(" tab_source ").reset();" value="Reset test 3">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(" myForm ").value=''" value="Reset test 4">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(" tab_source ").value=''" value="Reset test 5">

</form>
```

"Reset test 1" button only resets the last textarea ("tab_result").
Other buttons don't work at all.
Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good idea to write your JavaScript inside of your HTML for this reason. You should be getting errors for invalid syntax, but HTML gracefully ignores them and keeps on doing its thing.

 Keep your JavaScript in a `.js` file or inline in a `<script>` tag. Though your first button works as expected. It returns both textareas to their original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you ended the input attribute with: "

To showcase it to you, it looks like this:

```
<input attribute="bla" attribute="bla" onClick="document.getElementById(" <!-- <- quotes determine end of onClick attribute.-->
```

Try:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset();" value="Reset test 2">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('tab_source').reset();" value="Reset test 3">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').value='';" value="Reset test 4">
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('tab_source').value='';" value="Reset test 5">
```

Comment: you're welcome (: If it worked and you consider it as an answer, may you please mark it? That would be nice thank you (: